# Rota resulta em 404 Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, rotas

Estava seguindo o tutorial de inicialização do CodeIgniter quando me deparei com um problema com rotas.

o arquivo de rotas está com as seguintes rotas:

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Um exemplo de controller poderia ser o `Pages`:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/pages/' . $page . '.php'))
            show_404();

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Quando chamado pelo default_controller ele é executado normalmente, mas quando tento entrar em uma rota diferente é exibido um **Not Found** do *Apache*.

Já verifiquei se todas classes estão com os arquivos iniciados em letra maiúscula, o módulo rewrite está ativo, e no config.php só alterei o:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://estudo.local/ci/';
```

O **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Qual seria o problema?

Comment: Como está o arquivo .htaccess?

Comment: Não esqueceu de colocar ele?

Comment: Coloquei ele na pergunta, não alterei nada nele pois no tutorial não dizia nada sobre ele então confiei por seu um tutorial oficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca o arquivo .htaccess da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```